# How to change string font color using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

EDIT: I am creating a dashboard for my company that displays all of our latest projects. I'm an intern for the application development team. The dashboard displays the names of the projects and their latest builds, as well as the statuses of those builds.

I'm using a dynamic string that changes between SUCCESS, FAILURE, ERROR, and UNKNOWN. These strings are displayed in HTML using td class="status". The statuses can change based on whether a project build failed or succeeded. SUCCESS should be green, FAILURE should be red, and all others should be black. I have a for loop creating the table.

I'm attempting to use a switch statement to change the font color based on the content of the string using javascript's function .fontcolor(). The string is getting pulled from status.status

At the moment everything is displaying properly on the screen but the font color is not actually changing. I'm not getting any errors either.

```
for (var i in buildstatuses) {
                var status = buildstatuses[i];


                switch (status.status) {
                    case "SUCCESS":
                        status.status.fontcolor("green")
                        break;
                    case "FAILURE":
                        status.status.fontcolor("red")
                        break;
                    default:
                        status.status.fontcolor("black")
                        break;
                }

                $("tr#" + status.id + " td.status").html(status.status)

                if (status.status != "SUCCESS") {

                    var row = $("tr#" + status.id)


                           row.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().removeClass("dashboard-success").addClass("dashboard-fail");

                    row.parent().parent().prepend(row.clone());  // Places Failure at the top by cloning then removing
                    row.remove();

                }
                $("tr#" + status.id + " td.date").html(status.date)
                console.log(status.id);
            }
```

Comment: Before beimg able to understand this... What is "status.status" or "status" for that matter? What is everything? ... I'll try answering it though. Well Gaby was faster, exactly what I wanted to answer :D

Comment: You could just do it using JavaScript `style` function:
EX:
document.getElementById('yourId').style.color = 'red';

or use jquery:
$('#yourid').css('color','red')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to change the css color inline:

```
var statusColor = 'black';
switch (status.status) {
  case "SUCCESS":
    statusColor = "green";
    break;
  case "FAILURE":
    statusColor = "red";
    break;
  default:
    statusColor = "black";
    break;
 }

 $("tr#" + status.id + " td.status").html(status.status).css('color', statusColor);
```

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly, thank you so much. I will check this as an answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

I will move that to a little function

```
function ChangeColor(result)
{
    var item=$(".status");
    if(result=="SUCCESS")
        item.css("color","green");
    if(result=="FAILURE")
        item.css("color","red");    
}
```

You can call it like this

```
ChangeColor("FAILURE");
```

or

```
ChangeColor("SUCCESS");
```

So in your code,

```
for (var i in buildstatuses) {
    var status = buildstatuses[i];
    ChangeColor(status.status);

   //your remaining code to do whatver you want after changing the color
}
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/gVV3U/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the color in your HTML..

Change

```
$("tr#" + status.id + " td.status").html(status.status)
```

to

```
$("tr#" + status.id + " td.status")
        .html(status.status) // set text
        .css({color: status.status.fontcolor}); // set color
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it using JavaScript `style` function: EX:

`document.getElementById('yourId').style.color = 'red';`

or use jquery:

```
 $('#yourid').css('color','red');
```

Comment: Because of the way the project was set up there is only one class for all statuses (td class="status") so changing the css color will change all of the statuses to one color.